# NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method decrementAndGet

Tags: android, apache-commons-lang3

On *some* devices my app crashes with

`Exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method decrementAndGet()I in class Lorg/apache/commons/lang3/mutable/MutableInt; or its super classes (declaration of 'org.apache.commons.lang3.mutable.MutableInt' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar:classes2.dex)`

From what I know (I may be wrong), Android devices already have the *apache commons lang3* library.

I am also including it with my app (as a dependency), but it seems the one actually loaded on the classpath is not the one I provided but an older version where that method doesn't exist.

**Is there a way to instruct gradle to force usage of the *apache commons lang3* version defined in my apk instead of the one provided by the system?**

Comment: did you try to load it as dependency? The classpath dependencies are for build.gradle

Comment: @KostasDrak You mean add the dependency to `dependencies` inside `buildscript` and it will force the correct version to be loaded?

Comment: add dependency to dependencies into the build.gradle for the app module. Then it will be loaded normally

Comment: @KostasDrak It's already added as a dependency there, but the system provided one is loaded first, as it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From what I know (I may be wrong), Android devices already have the apache commons lang3 library

If it is, it is undocumented. It also may be that [only certain device manufacturers are loading it in the zygote](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/12/11/manufacturers-keep-your-hands-off-my-zygote.html) (the process from which all Android SDK apps' processes are forked), whereas it is not a problem on other devices from other manufacturers.

> it seems the one actually loaded on the classpath is not the one I provided but an older version where that method doesn't exist

Apps cannot override what is in the zygote. The zygote always wins.

> Is there a way to instruct gradle to force usage of the apache commons lang3 version defined in my apk instead of the one provided by the system?

No, sorry. I recommend not using that library.

Comment: Very informative blog post, thanks. You say you advise against that library. What do you recommend that contains many utility methods / classes, e.g. like the `MutableInt` I use? (creating my own is not an option)

Comment: @MinasMina: "What do you recommend that contains many utility methods / classes" -- don't choose libraries based upon their breadth and depth. If anything, choose smaller libraries, not larger ones. I do not know what `MutableInt` is giving you that you would not get from other solutions (`int`, `Integer`, `AtomicInteger`, `ObservableInt`, etc.) that are already part of the Android ecosystem.